# Is there a way I can use my Facebook chat from within Gmail?

Tags: google-talk, facebook-messenger

I like chatting with people through my Gmail account for a number of reasons, but mostly because these chats are archived and searchable.  Is it possible to use my Facebook chat from within Fmail chat so that I can have the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.  Google allows you to additionally sign on to AOL instant messenger, but not Facebook chat.

However, you can use a 3rd party app [Trillian for example] or web-based chat sites that integrate with both Gtalk and Facebook chat.

Answer (score 2):

Google chat is XMPP. Facebook provides an XMPP interface. Any 3rd party chat client supporting XMPP (Trillian, Empathy, Pidgin, etc.) will support both of these but there is no way to use FB chat inside gmail itself.

**Amendment**

Perhaps one could write a greasemonkey script to do what you want but that would be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

[Try Psi.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1093045)

> 1. Install IM PSI or similar (http://psi-im.org/download)
> 2. Add XMPP account "user@gmail,com" (gtalk account), login and go online
> 3. Click on "General/Service discovery" and into the address put "j2j.jabber.org.by" (wish other service? http://www.jabberes.org/servers/)
> 4. Right button click on the "XMPP j2j Transport" and click "Register"
>
>    - jabberid: "fb_username@chat.facebook.com"
>    - Password: your fb password
> 5. Click "Register"
> 6. Add and auth everything